# NSCollectionView inside another NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, binding, nscollectionview

I have these two classes:

```
@interface Father : NSObject
{
     NSString* name;
     NSArray* listChildren;
}

@property (copy, readwrite) NSString* name;
@property (copy, readwrite) NSArray* listChildren;

@end

@interface Child : NSObject
{
     NSString* nameChild;
     NSImage* picture;
}

@property (copy, readwrite) NSString* nameChild;
@property (copy, readwrite) NSImage* picture;

@end
```

I'm trying to make a `NSCollectionView` filled with `Father` items, and for each father item's `View` i will have a name label, and another `NSCollectionView` filled with the (father) `representedObject.listChildren` items.

I've managed to create an external NIB file for the father `NSCollectionViewItem`'s `View` to make things easier, but I'm not able to bind the child `CollectionView` to the `representedObject.listChildren` property. Actually, there is no problem in binding in IB, and at runtime the system is actually calling the property (I've added and `getListChildren` implementation and a NSLog call to make sure the property is being called). It seems that the inner `CollectionView`'s won't load the items found in my `NSArray`* property?

It is driving me crazy, any ideas about what is going on? 
Help please!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204147/debugging-nested-nscollectionviews
No answers there, either. Argh!

Comment: Any updates or answers to these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I found the solution!

I'm a complete novice to Objective C and Cocoa so I don't fully understand the reasons why this does not work exactly. Maybe somebody else can enlighten us.

In my first try I simply did everything in the default `MainMenu.xib`. You end up with two `NSArrayController` this way. Now apparently, as you suspected, the issue lies with the second `NSArrayController` for the inner items. It somehow doesn't get "copied" correctly. Extracting each `NSView` into its own `.xib` solves this issue.

Actually this [discussion](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/283883-attempt-to-nest-an-nscollectionview-fails.html) got me started in the right direction. I later discovered/understood that this is the basically the same idea @user493638 already hinted at.

Combining this knowledge with the tutorial [here](http://comelearncocoawithme.blogspot.de/2011/08/nscollectionview-redux.html), on how to extract the views into their own `.xib` solved the problem for me!

Again I don't understand Objective C and Cocoa nearly enough to fully appreciate the underlying reasons for this behavior, who knows how exactly all this binding magic works under the hood...

Comment: Can you share a sample of exactly what you did?